# VHDL Warnings that my outputs are not connected to any drivers

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm currently working on building a generic n-bit ripple carry adder. But when I go to simulate my program, it is saying that my outputs are connected to any drivers and I'm getting U for every test case.

Here's my ripple carry adder code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity adder is
    generic (
        WIDTH : positive := 8); 
    port (
        x, y : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        cin  : in  std_logic;
        s    : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        cout : out std_logic);
end adder;

architecture RIPPLE_CARRY of adder is

    signal temp_carry : std_logic_vector(width downto 0);

begin  -- RIPPLE_CARRY

U_ADD : for i in 0 to width-1 generate

    U_FA : entity work.fa port map (
    input1 => x(i),
    input2 => y(i),
    carry_in => temp_carry(i),
    sum => s(i),
    carry_out => temp_carry(i+1)
);

end generate U_ADD;

temp_carry(0) <= cin;
cout <= temp_carry(width);


end RIPPLE_CARRY;
```

And here's what my FA looks like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN THE ENTITY

entity fa is
  port (
    input1    : in  std_logic;
    input2    : in  std_logic;
    carry_in  : in  std_logic;
    sum       : out std_logic;
   carry_out : out std_logic);
end fa;

-- DEFINE THE FULL ADDER HERE

architecture BHV of fa is
begin 
  carry_out <= (input1 and input2) or (input1 and carry_in) or (input2 
and carry_in);
  sum <= (input1 xor input2) xor carry_in;
end BHV;
```

Here's the warning I am getting in modelsim:

** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /adder_tb/U_RIPPLE_CARRY1/s(7 downto 0) has no driver.
 This port will contribute value (UUUUUUUU) to the signal network.
 ** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /adder_tb/U_RIPPLE_CARRY1/cout has no driver.
 This port will contribute value (U) to the signal network.

Here's the test bench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder_tb is
end adder_tb;

architecture TB of adder_tb is
    component adder
        generic (
            WIDTH : positive := 8);
        port (
            x, y : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
            cin  : in  std_logic;
            s    : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
            cout : out std_logic);
    end component;

    constant TEST_WIDTH  : positive := 8;
    constant TEST_WIDTH2 : positive := 4;

    signal x, y              : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal x2, y2            : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0);
    signal cin               : std_logic;
    signal s_rc              : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal s_rc2             : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0);
    signal s_cl              : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal s_cl2             : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0);
    signal s_h               : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal cout_rc, cout_rc2 : std_logic;
    signal cout_cl, cout_cl2 : std_logic;
    signal cout_h, cout_h2   : std_logic;
begin  -- TB

    U_RIPPLE_CARRY1 : adder
        generic map (
            WIDTH => TEST_WIDTH)
        port map (
            x    => x,
            y    => y,
            cin  => cin,
            s    => s_rc,
            cout => cout_rc);

    U_RIPPLE_CARRY2 : adder
        generic map (
            WIDTH => TEST_WIDTH2)
        port map (
            x    => x2,
            y    => y2,
            cin  => cin,
            s    => s_rc2,
            cout => cout_rc2);

    U_CARRY_LOOKAHEAD1 : adder
        generic map (
            WIDTH => TEST_WIDTH)
        port map (
            x    => x,
            y    => y,
            cin  => cin,
            s    => s_cl,
            cout => cout_cl);

    U_CARRY_LOOKAHEAD2 : adder
        generic map (
            WIDTH => TEST_WIDTH2)
        port map (
            x    => x2,
            y    => y2,
            cin  => cin,
            s    => s_cl2,
            cout => cout_cl2);

    U_HIERARCHICAL : adder
        generic map (
            WIDTH => 8)                 -- this architecture ignores the
                                        -- generic, fixed to size 8
        port map (
            x    => x,
            y    => y,
            cin  => cin,
            s    => s_h,
            cout => cout_h);

    process
        variable error_rc        : integer;
        variable error_cl        : integer;
        variable error_h         : integer;
        variable result_tmp      : unsigned(TEST_WIDTH downto 0);
        variable result_tmp2     : unsigned(TEST_WIDTH2 downto 0);
        variable correct_result  : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        variable correct_result2 : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0);
        variable correct_cout    : std_logic;

        variable score_rc  : integer;
        variable score_cla : integer;
        variable score_h   : integer;
    begin
        error_rc := 0;
        error_cl := 0;
        error_h  := 0;

        report "******************TESTING WIDTH = 8********************";

        for i in 0 to TEST_WIDTH-1 loop
            x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, TEST_WIDTH));
            for j in 0 to TEST_WIDTH-1 loop
                y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(j, TEST_WIDTH));
                for k in 0 to 1 loop
                    cin <= std_logic(to_unsigned(k, 1)(0));
                    wait for 10 ns;
                    result_tmp     := unsigned("0"&x) + unsigned("0"&y) + to_unsigned(k, 1);
                    correct_result := std_logic_vector(result_tmp(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0));
                    correct_cout   := std_logic(result_tmp(TEST_WIDTH));
                    if (s_rc /= correct_result) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(s_rc))) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (cout_rc /= correct_cout) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, carry from " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & std_logic'image(cout_rc) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (s_cl /= correct_result) then
                        error_cl := error_cl + 1;
                        report "Error : CL, " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(s_cl))) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (cout_cl /= correct_cout) then
                        error_cl := error_cl + 1;
                        report "Error : CL, carry from " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & std_logic'image(cout_cl) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (s_h /= correct_result) then
                        error_h := error_h + 1;
                        report "Error : HEIR, " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(s_h))) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (cout_h /= correct_cout) then
                        error_h := error_h + 1;
                        report "Error : HEIR, carry from " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & std_logic'image(cout_h) severity warning;
                    end if;
                end loop;  -- k
            end loop;  -- j      
        end loop;  -- i
        report "******************TESTING WIDTH = 4********************";

        -- Test a different width
        for i in 0 to TEST_WIDTH2-1 loop
            x2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, TEST_WIDTH2));
            for j in 0 to TEST_WIDTH2-1 loop
                y2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(j, TEST_WIDTH2));
                for k in 0 to 1 loop
                    cin <= std_logic(to_unsigned(k, 1)(0));
                    wait for 10 ns;
                    result_tmp2     := unsigned("0"&x2) + unsigned("0"&y2) + to_unsigned(k, 1);
                    correct_result2 := std_logic_vector(result_tmp2(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0));
                    correct_cout    := std_logic(result_tmp2(TEST_WIDTH2));
                    if (s_rc2 /= correct_result2) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(s_rc2))) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (cout_rc2 /= correct_cout) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, carry from " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & std_logic'image(cout_rc2) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (s_cl2 /= correct_result2) then
                        error_cl := error_cl + 1;
                        report "Error : CL, " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(s_cl2))) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (cout_cl2 /= correct_cout) then
                        error_cl := error_cl + 1;
                        report "Error : CL, carry from " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & std_logic'image(cout_cl2) severity warning;
                    end if;
                end loop;  -- k
            end loop;  -- j      
        end loop;  -- i

        report "Ripple carry errors    : " & integer'image(error_rc);
        report "Carry lookahead errors : " & integer'image(error_cl);
        report "Heirarchical errors    : " & integer'image(error_h);

        score_rc  := 20 - error_rc;
        score_cla := 30 - error_cl;
        score_h   := 50 - error_h;

        if score_rc < 0 then
            score_rc := 0;
        end if;
        if score_cla < 0 then
            score_cla := 0;
        end if;
        if score_h < 0 then
            score_h := 0;
        end if;

        report "RIPPLE_CARRY SCORE = " & integer'image(score_rc);
        report "CLA SCORE = " & integer'image(score_cla);
        report "HEIRARCHICAL SCORE = " & integer'image(score_h);
        wait;
    end process;
end TB;


configuration TB_CONFIG of adder_tb is
    for TB
        for U_RIPPLE_CARRY1 : adder
            use entity work.adder(RIPPLE_CARRY);
        end for;
        for U_RIPPLE_CARRY2 : adder
            use entity work.adder(RIPPLE_CARRY);
        end for;
        for U_CARRY_LOOKAHEAD1 : adder
            use entity work.adder(CARRY_LOOKAHEAD);
        end for;
        for U_CARRY_LOOKAHEAD2 : adder
            use entity work.adder(CARRY_LOOKAHEAD);
        end for;
        for U_HIERARCHICAL : adder
            use entity work.adder(HIERARCHICAL);
        end for;
    end for;
end TB_CONFIG;
```

Comment: Code looks OK at a glance. Check that (the correct version of) FA is compiled into the right place before compiling ADDER; what you're seeing suggests otherwise.

Comment: Show us `adder_tb` please.

Comment: Added the test bench, there's tests for other adders that I am suppose to implement for this project.

Comment: FA works I've tested it for a prior project, so it's def not the problem. It's also in my modelsim project's working library and has been compiled.

Comment: You've supplied architecture RIPPLE_CARRY of adder while your testbench instantiates architectures carry_lookahead and hierarchical which may not be bound (not found in the working library for an entity instantiation). Is your TB_CONFIG configuration declaration correct? Are you simulating it?

Comment: carry_lookahead and hierarchical are for future implementations of adders that I need to do after getting RIPPLE_CARRY to work.

Comment: Any other vcom or vsim messages (warnings/errors)? I haven't found any verror messages for IEEE Std 1076-1993 12.3.2.2 Configuration specifications (14.4.3.3 -2008) where *As part of this elaboration process, a check is made that both the entity declaration and the corresponding architecture body implied by the binding indication exist within the specified library. It is an error if this check fails.* If you had been simulating TB_CONFIG without architectures carry_lookahead and hierarchical having been analyzed you should have received an elaboration error.

Comment: When attempting to simulate adder_tb instead of TB_CONFIG  or commenting out the architecture bindings in the configuration specifications of configuration TB_CONFIG and simulating TB_CONFIG your testbench passes.

Comment: Did your professor write that test bench? I hope not...

Comment: He did? Why whats wrong with it?

Comment: It is coding quality I'd expect from a *junior* engineer. This could have been greatly simplified using functions, procedures and polymorphism. Even the signal/variable naming is bad. Edit: sorry, personal frustration. I often have to maintain code which was written poorly. But how will people ever learn to write good code, if their teachers are also bad at coding?

Comment: That's the struggle I'm going through currently... Terrible at VHDL but the teacher really isn't helping with learning it, and the skeleton code he gives us for projects generally makes no sense to me.

Comment: I fully agree on this. You'll have to find your own path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take the test bench and remove all the not connected elements from the test bench, the simulation works perfectly:

> # ** Note: ******************TESTING WIDTH = 8********************
>
> #    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /adder_tb
>
> # ** Note: ******************TESTING WIDTH = 4********************
>
> #    Time: 1280 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /adder_tb
>
> # ** Note: Ripple carry errors    : 0
>
> #    Time: 1600 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /adder_tb
>
> # ** Note: RIPPLE_CARRY SCORE = 20
>
> #    Time: 1600 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /adder_tb

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity adder_tb is
end adder_tb;

architecture TB of adder_tb is
    component adder
        generic (
            WIDTH : positive := 8);
        port (
            x, y : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
            cin  : in  std_logic;
            s    : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
            cout : out std_logic);
    end component;

    constant TEST_WIDTH  : positive := 8;
    constant TEST_WIDTH2 : positive := 4;

    signal x, y              : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal x2, y2            : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0);
    signal cin               : std_logic;
    signal s_rc              : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal s_rc2             : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0);
    signal cout_rc, cout_rc2 : std_logic;
begin  -- TB

    U_RIPPLE_CARRY1 : adder
        generic map (
            WIDTH => TEST_WIDTH)
        port map (
            x    => x,
            y    => y,
            cin  => cin,
            s    => s_rc,
            cout => cout_rc);

    U_RIPPLE_CARRY2 : adder
        generic map (
            WIDTH => TEST_WIDTH2)
        port map (
            x    => x2,
            y    => y2,
            cin  => cin,
            s    => s_rc2,
            cout => cout_rc2);

    process
        variable error_rc        : integer;
        use ieee.numeric_std.all;
        variable result_tmp      : unsigned(TEST_WIDTH downto 0);
        variable result_tmp2     : unsigned(TEST_WIDTH2 downto 0);
        variable correct_result  : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        variable correct_result2 : std_logic_vector(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0);
        variable correct_cout    : std_logic;

        variable score_rc  : integer;
    begin
        error_rc := 0;

        report "******************TESTING WIDTH = 8********************";

        for i in 0 to TEST_WIDTH-1 loop
            x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, TEST_WIDTH));
            for j in 0 to TEST_WIDTH-1 loop
                y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(j, TEST_WIDTH));
                for k in 0 to 1 loop
                    cin <= std_logic(to_unsigned(k, 1)(0));
                    wait for 10 ns;
                    result_tmp     := unsigned("0"&x) + unsigned("0"&y) + to_unsigned(k, 1);
                    correct_result := std_logic_vector(result_tmp(TEST_WIDTH-1 downto 0));
                    correct_cout   := std_logic(result_tmp(TEST_WIDTH));
                    if (s_rc /= correct_result) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(s_rc))) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (cout_rc /= correct_cout) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, carry from " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & std_logic'image(cout_rc) severity warning;
                    end if;
                end loop;  -- k
            end loop;  -- j      
        end loop;  -- i
        report "******************TESTING WIDTH = 4********************";

        -- Test a different width
        for i in 0 to TEST_WIDTH2-1 loop
            x2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, TEST_WIDTH2));
            for j in 0 to TEST_WIDTH2-1 loop
                y2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(j, TEST_WIDTH2));
                for k in 0 to 1 loop
                    cin <= std_logic(to_unsigned(k, 1)(0));
                    wait for 10 ns;
                    result_tmp2     := unsigned("0"&x2) + unsigned("0"&y2) + to_unsigned(k, 1);
                    correct_result2 := std_logic_vector(result_tmp2(TEST_WIDTH2-1 downto 0));
                    correct_cout    := std_logic(result_tmp2(TEST_WIDTH2));
                    if (s_rc2 /= correct_result2) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(s_rc2))) severity warning;
                    end if;
                    if (cout_rc2 /= correct_cout) then
                        error_rc := error_rc + 1;
                        report "Error : RC, carry from " & integer'image(i) & " + " & integer'image(j) & " + " & integer'image(k) & " = " & std_logic'image(cout_rc2) severity warning;
                    end if;
                end loop;  -- k
            end loop;  -- j      
        end loop;  -- i

        report "Ripple carry errors    : " & integer'image(error_rc);

        score_rc  := 20 - error_rc;

        if score_rc < 0 then
            score_rc := 0;
        end if;

        report "RIPPLE_CARRY SCORE = " & integer'image(score_rc);
        wait;
    end process;
end TB;


configuration TB_CONFIG of adder_tb is
    for TB
        for U_RIPPLE_CARRY1 : adder
            use entity work.adder(RIPPLE_CARRY);
        end for;
        for U_RIPPLE_CARRY2 : adder
            use entity work.adder(RIPPLE_CARRY);
        end for;
    end for;
end TB_CONFIG;
```